# segmentation fault when using a non NULL pointer

Tags: c, linux, gcc, segmentation-fault, dpdk

there is a weird problem as title when using dpdk,

When I use rte_pktmbuf_alloc(struct rte_mempool *) and already verify the return value of rte_pktmbuf_pool_create() is not NULL, the process receive segmentation fault.

Follow

```
ing message is output of gdb in dpdk source code:

Thread 1 "osw" received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.

0x00000000005e9f41 in __mempool_generic_get (cache=0x1a7dfc000000000, n=1, obj_table=0x7fffffffdec8, mp=0x101a7df00)at /root/dpdk-20.05/x86_64-native-linuxapp-gcc/include/rte_mempool.h:1449

1449            if (unlikely(cache == NULL || n >= cache->size))

(gdb) p cache

$1 = (struct rte_mempool_cache *) 0x1a7dfc000000000

(gdb) bt

0  0x00000000005e9f41 in __mempool_generic_get (cache=0x1a7dfc000000000, n=1, obj_table=0x7fffffffdeb8, mp=0x101a7df00)

   at /root/dpdk-20.05/x86_64-native-linuxapp-gcc/include/rte_mempool.h:1449

1  rte_mempool_generic_get (cache=0x1a7dfc000000000, n=1, obj_table=0x7fffffffdeb8, mp=0x101a7df00)

   at /root/dpdk-20.05/x86_64-native-linuxapp-gcc/include/rte_mempool.h:1517

2  rte_mempool_get_bulk (n=1, obj_table=0x7fffffffdeb8, mp=0x101a7df00)

   at /root/dpdk-20.05/x86_64-native-linuxapp-gcc/include/rte_mempool.h:1552

3  rte_mempool_get (obj_p=0x7fffffffdeb8, mp=0x101a7df00) at /root/dpdk-20.05/x86_64-native-linuxapp-gcc/include/rte_mempool.h:1578

4  rte_mbuf_raw_alloc (mp=0x101a7df00) at /root/dpdk-20.05/x86_64-native-linuxapp-gcc/include/rte_mbuf.h:586

5  rte_pktmbuf_alloc (mp=0x101a7df00) at /root/dpdk-20.05/x86_64-native-linuxapp-gcc/include/rte_mbuf.h:896
```

And I dig into rte_mempool.h:

and change line 1449-1450

```
1449  if (unlikely(cache == NULL || n >= cache->size))

1450         goto ring_dequeue;
```

to

```
1449  if (unlikely(cache == NULL))

1450          goto ring_dequeue;

1451  if (unlikely(n >= cache->size))

1452          goto ring_dequeue;
```

and it also fail at line 1451

the gdb output message after changing:

```
Thread 1 "osw" received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.

__mempool_generic_get (cache=0x1a7dfc000000000, n=1, obj_table=0x7fffffffdeb8, mp=0x101a7df00)
   at /root/dpdk-20.05/x86_64-native-linuxapp-gcc/include/rte_mempool.h:1451

1451            if (unlikely(n >= cache->size))

(gdb) p cache

$1 = (struct rte_mempool_cache *) 0x1a7dfc000000000

(gdb) bt

0  __mempool_generic_get (cache=0x1a7dfc000000000, n=1, obj_table=0x7fffffffdeb8, mp=0x101a7df00)

   at /root/dpdk-20.05/x86_64-native-linuxapp-gcc/include/rte_mempool.h:1451

1  rte_mempool_generic_get (cache=0x1a7dfc000000000, n=1, obj_table=0x7fffffffdeb8, mp=0x101a7df00)

   at /root/dpdk-20.05/x86_64-native-linuxapp-gcc/include/rte_mempool.h:1519

2  rte_mempool_get_bulk (n=1, obj_table=0x7fffffffdeb8, mp=0x101a7df00)

   at /root/dpdk-20.05/x86_64-native-linuxapp-gcc/include/rte_mempool.h:1554

3  rte_mempool_get (obj_p=0x7fffffffdeb8, mp=0x101a7df00) at /root/dpdk-20.05/x86_64-native-linuxapp-gcc/include/rte_mempool.h:1580

4  rte_mbuf_raw_alloc (mp=0x101a7df00) at /root/dpdk-20.05/x86_64-native-linuxapp-gcc/include/rte_mbuf.h:586

5  rte_pktmbuf_alloc (mp=0x101a7df00) at /root/dpdk-20.05/x86_64-native-linuxapp-gcc/include/rte_mbuf.h:896

6  main (argc=<optimized out>, argv=<optimized out>) at ofpd.c:150

(gdb) p cache->size

Cannot access memory at address 0x1a7dfc000000000
```

It looks like the memory address “cache” pointer stored is not NULL but it actually is a NULL pointer.

I have no idea that why does the "cache" pointer address be non zero at prefix 4 bytes and zero at postfix 4 bytes.

The DPDK version is 20.05, I also tried 18.11 and 19.11.

OS is CentOS 8.1 kernel is 4.18.0-147.el8.x86_64.

CPU is AMD EPYC 7401P.

```
#define                 RING_SIZE       16384
#define                 NUM_MBUFS       8191
#define                 MBUF_CACHE_SIZE 512

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int             ret;
    uint16_t        portid;
    unsigned        cpu_id = 1;
    struct rte_mempool  *tmp;

    int arg = rte_eal_init(argc, argv);
    if (arg < 0) 
        rte_exit(EXIT_FAILURE, "Cannot init EAL: %s\n", rte_strerror(rte_errno));
    if (rte_lcore_count() < 10)
        rte_exit(EXIT_FAILURE, "We need at least 10 cores.\n");
    argc -= arg;
    argv += arg;

    /* Creates a new mempool in memory to hold the mbufs. */
    tmp = rte_pktmbuf_pool_create("TMP", NUM_MBUFS, MBUF_CACHE_SIZE, 0, RTE_MBUF_DEFAULT_BUF_SIZE, rte_socket_id());
    if (tmp == NULL)
        rte_exit(EXIT_FAILURE, "Cannot create mbuf pool, %s\n", rte_strerror(rte_errno));
    printf("tmp addr = %x\n", tmp);
    struct rte_mbuf *test = rte_pktmbuf_alloc(tmp);
    rte_exit(EXIT_FAILURE, "end\n");
}
```

I have ever faced same problem when using the return pointer of getifaddrs(), it also got segmentation fault, I had to shift the pointer address like

```
ifa->ifa_addr = (struct sockaddr *)((uintptr_t)(ifa->ifa_addr) >> 32);
```

and then it can work normally.

Thereforer, I think this is not dpdk specific issue.

Does anyone know this issue?

Thanks.

Comment: Start by running your code through valgrind.  You may be mismanaging memory, and if so it will tell you where.

Comment: I have minimize my code to just calling init function provided by dpdk and then call the above function call. The problem still exist. I also tried valgrind and there is no any leaked memory and memory error.

Comment: You're going to have to trace back in the code to see where that value of `cache` came from.  It may be some sort of 32 vs 64 bit mismatch issue, where you're reading something that was intended to be a 32-bit null pointer, but you're reading 64 bits and so the high 32 bits contain some nonzero garbage.

Comment: It sounds like you've created a [mcve], can you post it?

Comment: @NateEldredge The cache which is a pointer is defined in dpdk library, not declared by me. I have tried compile my previous project using the same dpdk function call, it works normally. Is there any chance it is caused by my linked library which is not from dpdk to cause the 32 bit-64 bit issue? I have also posted my minimal reproducible code, thanks for mention me for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to run this without any error by modifying your code for

1. include headers
2. removed unused variables
3. add check if the returned value is NULL or not for `alloc`

Test on:

```
CPU: Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2699
OS: 4.15.0-101-generic
GCC: 7.5.0
DPDK version: 19.11.2, dpdk mainline
Library mode: static
```

code:

```
 int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int             ret = 0;
    struct rte_mempool  *tmp;

    int arg = rte_eal_init(argc, argv);
    if (arg < 0)
        rte_exit(EXIT_FAILURE, "Cannot init EAL: %s\n", rte_strerror(rte_errno));
    if (rte_lcore_count() < 10)
        rte_exit(EXIT_FAILURE, "We need at least 10 cores.\n");
    argc -= arg;
    argv += arg;

    /* Creates a new mempool in memory to hold the mbufs. */
    tmp = rte_pktmbuf_pool_create("TMP", NUM_MBUFS, MBUF_CACHE_SIZE, 0, RTE_MBUF_DEFAULT_BUF_SIZE, rte_socket_id());
    if (tmp == NULL)
        rte_exit(EXIT_FAILURE, "Cannot create mbuf pool, %s\n", rte_strerror(rte_errno));
    printf("tmp addr = %p\n", tmp);
    struct rte_mbuf *test = rte_pktmbuf_alloc(tmp);

    if (test == NULL)
        rte_exit(EXIT_FAILURE, "end\n");

   return ret;
}
```

[EDIT-1] based on the comment `Brydon Gibson`

Note:

1. As I do not have access to your codebase or working code snippet my suggestion is *to lookup any example code from DPDK/examples/l2fwd or DPDK/examples/skeleton and copy the headers for your compilation.*
2. I assume both the author `THE` and `Brydon` are different individuals and might be facing similar on the different code bases.
3. current question claims with DPDK version 20.05, 18.11 and 19.11 the error is reproduced with code snippet.
4. current answer clearly sates with **static linking** of the library the same code snippet works

Requested @BrydonGibson to open the ticket with relevant information and environment details as it might be different.

Comment: Thanks for help, now I doubt whether is my own library cause this issue. The only unconfirmed factor is I link a library I programmed, I will check this and report the result.

Comment: if there is no issue with the code and accept the findings are correct. please upvote and accept the answer

Comment: This answer appears to be lacking detail - "Include headers" Which headers? "Add check if the returned value is NULL for alloc" this doesn't solve _why_ `rte_pktmbuf_alloc` is returning null (or in my case, segfaulting, which is why I'm here)

Comment: The original author `THE` has posted the question with a code snippet (no headers included) for error reproduction. Using the same code snippet, it is easy to compile and test without any error on HOST and Guest OS. The same has been updated in the answer suggesting author `THE` there is no issue in DPDK API or libraries for the suggested version. I have to assume both `THE` and `BrydonGibson` is different person and problem faced are different, so I humbly disagree and suggest to open a ticket with relevant information and code snippet. I am happy to look into the same for you.